# About android files in fat32 SD card, does it also have permission?

Tags: android, fat32, ext3

unlike ext3 file system, fat32 is not a native Linux file system

that is have user permission status tag in it.

So, does this mean all user/app can read/write SD card files?

Comment: To write on the external SD you need the "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" permission. But yes, you are right, FAT32 doesn't provide a file specific permission system.

Comment: u only need to use *android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE* , FAT32 doesn't need any other specific permision

Comment: can android mount an ext3 SD card?